# Swift Combine two handlers for one property

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a `UIViewController` which using `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`. I have a view-model for this controller which looks something like:

```
class ListViewModel {
    @Published private(set) var items: [Item] = []
    
    func load(params: [String: Any] = [:]) {
        WebRepo().index(params: params, completion: { [weak self] (items, error) in
            self?.items = items
        })
    }
    
    func deleteFirst() {
        self.items.remove(object: self.items.first)
    }
}
```

In my VC, I have a binding like:

```
self.viewModel.$items.sink { [weak self] (scenes) in
    self?.update(items: items, animated: false)
}.store(in: &self.subscriptions)
```

So, when I'm calling my view-model's `load` method - I want to do `self?.update(items: items, animated: false)`, but when I'm calling `deleteFirst` - I want `self?.update(items: items, animated: true)`.

I'm quite new to reactive and Combine, so not sure what is the proper way to handle this.
I can add `isReset` property to my view-model and change `load` method to something like:

```
    func load(params: [String: Any] = [:]) {
        WebRepo().index(params: params, completion: { [weak self] (items, error) in
            self?.isReset = true
            self?.items = items
            self?.isReset = false
        })
    }
```

And inside `sink` just check this property, but it does not look as a proper way for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way of thinking about it. Instead of publishing `items`, use a PassthroughSubject whose output type is a tuple, `([Items], Bool)`. And the view controller subscribes to that subject.

Now, when you call `load`, call the passthrough subject's `send` with `(items, false)`, but when you call `delete`, call the passthrough subject's `send` with `(items, true)`.

In other words, take it upon your publisher to publish *all* the information that the downstream would need in order to know what to do.

You might think that this approach is rather extreme, but clumping things together into a tuple in order to pass multiple pieces of info down the pipeline is *normal* behavior. Really, this is the reactive equivalent of calling a method with two parameters.

---

Another possibility might be for the downstream to consider how many times this publisher has published. This would work if, for example, the ViewModel is going to call `load` only once. If that's the case, the downstream pipeline would be able to use operators (such as `scan`, or `first`, or whatever) to distinguish the first value that comes down the pipeline (which means we want not to animate) from any subsequent values (where we do want to animate).

---

Yet another way to think of this would be to put the onus entirely on whoever is building the snapshot. If the diffable data source's snapshot is empty, it has no data and we do not want to animate. If is not empty, we do want to animate. Again, that would work only if applicable to your purposes.

Comment: (Irrelevantly to this question, you should also be changing your WebRepo call to be reactive. A completion handler is the opposite of Combine! You should be using a pipeline that starts with a (deferred) future that does the networking.)

Comment: Hi @matt, thanks. I was thinking about to use tuple, but I thought it is kind of workaround rather than proper way :). I can't use `first` or can't pass this to data source, because user can do reload anytime with pull to refresh.

Comment: BTW, for tuple no need to use `PassthroughSubject`, we can use `self.items = (newItems, true)`

Comment: For anyone interested, I changed WebRepo call to be reactive, and had some issues also with it, which discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64697969/alamofire-combine-mvvm-request-example/64699777