# Alamofire + Combine + MVVM request example

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, combine

in my view controller I have a property `items` to which I have a subscription and rendering my view.

For this view controller I have a view model where I have load method like:

```
    @Published private(set) var items: [Item] = []

    func load(params: [String: Any] = [:]) {
        self.isLoading = true
        
        self.subscription = WebRepo().index(params: params).sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] (completion) in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            default: break
            }
            self?.isLoading = false
        }, receiveValue: { [weak self] (response) in
            self?.items = response.data
        })
    }
```

and my `WebRepo` looks like:

```
final class WebRepo {
    func index(params: [String: Any]) -> AnyPublisher<MyResponse<[Item]>, Error> {
        let url = URL(...)
        return AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params)
        .publishDecodable(type: MyResponse<[Item]>.self)
        .tryCompactMap { (response) -> MyResponse<[Item]>? in
            if let error = response.error { throw error }
            return response.value
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

My user can load multiple times and as you can see It will subscribe each time when `load` method is called, which I think should not be like this.

I tried to introduce property for my view model:

```
private var indexResponse: AnyPublisher<MyResponse<[Item]>, Error>?

//And my load becomes

func load(params: [String: Any] = [:]) {
   self.isLoading = true
   self.indexResponse = WebRepo().index(params: params)
}
```

But in this case I can't make initial binding since initial value is `nil` hence it won't subscribe.

Another question is about handling error from load, do I need to have property for `error` inside view model or is there way I can rethrow an error for `$items`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a single subscription in `init` with a `PassthroughSubject` as a trigger, and `.send` inside `load`:

```
private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
private let loadTrigger = PassthroughSubject<[String: Any], Never>()

init(...) {
   loadTrigger
     //.debounce(...) // possibly debounce load requests
     .flatMap { params in
         WebRepo().index(params: params)
     }
     .sink(
       receiveCompletion: {/* ... */},
       receiveValue: {/* ... */})
     .store(in: &cancellables)
}

func load(params: [String: Any] = [:]) {
    loadTrigger.send(params)
}
```

I can't tell you how to handle the error, since it's very case specific and probably subjective, e.g. should an error terminate the subscription? do you plan to handle possible multiple errors?

---

If you want to never fail, but still handle an error as a side effect, you can return [`Result`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result), which would capture both value or error. This way, the pipeline could have a failure type of `Never`, so it would never terminate due to error. Then you'd unwrap the result inside the `.sink`:

```
loadTrigger
   .flatMap { params -> AnyPublisher<Result<MyResponse<[Item]>, Error>, Never> in
       WebRepo().index(params: params)
          .map { .success($0) }
          .catch { Just(.failure($0)) }
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()
   }
   .sink { [weak self] result in
       switch result {
       case success(let response): 
           self?.items = response.data
       case failure(let err):
           // do something with the error
       }
   }
```

Comment: About error - just one simple error which will show alert and user can retry this request. But in this case when error happens it stops subscription, hence user can't retry this request one more time.

Comment: @AlexZd, updated with a possible approach to handle errors

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. As for me this reactive way of requesting looks quite difficult compared to simple callbacks approach. Not sure about reactive benefits in this example, maybe because it is too simple :)

Comment: @AlexZd It's just a matter of learning to think this way. You'll get used to it (if you want to).